# Concatenate constraints in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

My question is, how I concatenate constrains in the clausule with of phpunit?
In the dummy example:

```
$test->expects ($this->once())
     ->method ('increaseValue')
     ->with ($this->greaterThan (0)
     ->will ($this->returnValue (null));
```

The parameter of the method **increaseValue** must be greater than 0, but If I need evaluate that this parameter must be less than 10.

How I concatenate `$this->lessThan(10)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `logicalAnd` expression:

```
$test->expects ($this->once())
     ->method ('increaseValue')
     ->with ($this->logicalAnd($this->greaterThan(0), $this->lessThan(10)))
     ->will ($this->returnValue (null));
```

For a list of possible functions check the functions in: [`PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php#L2097) that don't start with "assert"

### Complete Example

```
<?php

class mockMe {
    public function increaseValue($x) {
    }
}


class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testMock() {
        $test = $this->getMock('mockMe');
        $test->expects($this->once())
             ->method('increaseValue')
             ->with($this->logicalAnd($this->greaterThan(0), $this->lessThan(10)))
             ->will($this->returnValue(null));
        $test->increaseValue(6);
    }

    public function testMockFails() {
        $test = $this->getMock('mockMe');
        $test->expects($this->once())
             ->method('increaseValue')
             ->with($this->logicalAnd($this->greaterThan(0), $this->lessThan(10)))
             ->will($this->returnValue(null));
        $test->increaseValue(12);
    }

}
```

### Result

```
 phpunit blub.php
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) fooTest::testMockFails
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:increaseValue> when invoked 1 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation mockMe::increaseValue(<integer:12>) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that <integer:12> is less than <integer:10>.

/home/.../blub.php:26
```